# Tmux will not stop auto-renaming windows

Tags: macos, tmux, oh-my-zsh

A problem I have with Tmux - in the `.tmux.conf` file I have told him not to rename windows after I set their names but it seems that it is not "respecting my authority" :).

**My system:**

- OSX El Capitan
- Tmux 2.1 (installed via Brew)
- Zshell

Here is my ~/.tmux.conf content (I apologise it's quite long):

```
# set correct term
set -g default-terminal screen-256color

# set prefix key to ctrl+a
#unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a 

# reload config without killing server
bind R source-file /users/edchigliak/.tmux.conf 

# enable wm window titles
set -g set-titles on

# disable auto renaming
set -g automatic-rename off

# border colour
set -g pane-border-fg blue
set -g pane-border-bg default
set -g pane-active-border-fg blue
set -g pane-active-border-bg default

# wm window title string (uses statusbar variables)
set -g set-titles-string "tmux:#I [ #W ]"

# initialize sessions
bind S source-file ~/.tmux.conf 
bind I source-file ~/.tmux.conf

# environment
set -g update-environment "DISPLAY SSH_ASKPASS SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_CONNECTION WINDOWID XAUTHORITY"

# statusbar --------------------------------------------------------------
set -g window-status-format "#I:#W"
set -g window-status-current-format "#I:#W"

set -g status-keys vi
bind-key -t vi-edit Up history-up
bind-key -t vi-edit Down history-down

set -g status-interval 1
set -g status-justify centre # center align window list

# default statusbar colors
# wm window title string (uses statusbar variables)
set -g set-titles-string "tmux:#I [ #W ]"

# initialize sessions
bind S source-file ~/.tmux.conf 
bind I source-file ~/.tmux.conf

# environment
set -g update-environment "DISPLAY SSH_ASKPASS SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_CONNECTION WINDOWID XAUTHORITY"

# statusbar --------------------------------------------------------------
set -g window-status-format "#I:#W"
set -g window-status-current-format "#I:#W"

set -g status-keys vi
bind-key -t vi-edit Up history-up
bind-key -t vi-edit Down history-down

set -g status-interval 1
set -g status-justify centre # center align window list

# default statusbar colors
set -g status-fg white
set -g status-bg default

# default window title colors
set-window-option -g window-status-fg black
set-window-option -g window-status-bg default
set-window-option -g window-status-attr dim

# active window title colors
set-window-option -g window-status-current-fg white
set-window-option -g window-status-current-bg default
set-window-option -g window-status-current-attr dim

# command/message line colors
set -g message-fg white
set -g message-bg black
set -g message-attr bright

# Statusbar starting in X or not
# if '[ -n "$DISPLAY" ]' 'source-file ~/.tmux/inx'
# if '[ -z "$DISPLAY" ]' 'source-file ~/.tmux/xless'
```

If I try:

> ~ > echo $TERM

I get the correct:

> screen-256color

which makes me believe that it is sourcing the right `.conf` file. Also, control key bindings DO change from `Ctrl+b` to `Ctrl+a`. However, window names that I change via `Ctrl + a` and then `,`simply will not stay put.

Any ideas what is going on? Thanks!

Comment: It is possible that it is `zsh`, which is changing your window titles, especially if the titles only change when you start a program or the shell prompt is issued. Any chance you could link your shell configuration? Otherwise look for `print` or `echo` statements with strings that start with `\e]2;` or `\033]2;` and end in `\a` or `\e\\` or `\033\\`.

Comment: You were right! ZSH was messing things up. I had to uncomment this line `export DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"` in my `.zshrc`. Please create an answer to my question and I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A likely cause for this is, that *zsh* is configured to update the window title when starting a program or issuing the prompt. This is done by using the terminal escape sequence `\ek<TEXT>\e\\` where `<TEXT>` is the window title.

To prevent this you have two options:

- #### Disallow window renaming in the *tmux* configuration.

  Just add

  ```
  set allow-rename off
  ```

  to your `~/.tmux.conf`. This prevents any program from changing the window title by using the aforementioned terminal escape sequence.
- #### Track down the setting in your *zsh* configuration and disable it.

  If you are using *oh-my-zsh*, it should be enough to set

  ```
  DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"
  ```

  in your `~/.zshrc` (or just uncomment it, if you are using the default `.zshrc` template from *oh-my-zsh*).

  If you use your own configuration or some other configuration framework, you should be able to track it down by searching for `\ek` (do not forget to quote the backslash if your search tool requires it).

Comment: ah, thankyou thankyou thankyou! This was KILLING me :) :) :)

Comment: please remember reload config file with `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`

Comment: I'd like to emphasize this setting is __per window__. If you create multiple windows from a script, you have to put `set allow-rename off` after every window creation command as that will be the active window at that moment.

Comment: Yes, I found that this only worked if I ran it in a tmux session. I used @Drew LeSueur answer in the end to have a permanent effect. Alternatively, I think `set-option -g allow-rename off` works too

Answer (score 12):

For people running bash and landing on this result, the thing that sets the title is the `PROMPT_COMMAND` environmental variable, which some shared system annoyingly set. You can do that with `unset PROMPT_COMMAND` (e.g. in your `.bashrc`)

Comment: Likewise, you might have a .vimrc setting causing the rename. Perhaps previously you followed this advice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123477/tmux-tabs-with-name-of-file-open-in-vim/15124717#15124717.

Comment: And not only the .vimrc, but other vim plugin like Nvim-r (https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R/)! If you still uses the tmux option as I do, the file : `Nvim-R/R/tmux_split.vim` rename the windows each you start R

Answer (score 5):

For this to work for me I had to add this line to ~/.tmux.conf

```
set-window-option -g allow-rename off
```