# vimscript t_ts for title, use two escape codes?

Tags: vim, ansi-escape

To set a tmux title in vim, you can do something like:

```
if hastmux == 'true' || &term == "screen" || &term == "screen-256color"
  set t_ts=^[]0;
  set t_fs=^G
endif
```

However, to update the window name, you need

```
if hastmux == 'true' || &term == "screen" || &term == "screen-256color"
  set t_ts=^[k
  set t_fs=^G
endif
```

Is there a way to specify two `t_ts`, or rather, to chain two ANSI codes together? I haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have 2 `t_ts`, of course, but you can achieve what you want making `vim` and `tmux` cooperate. Let `vim` set the title in `tmux` and let `tmux` set the title in window. In vim:

```
set t_ts=^[k
set t_fs=^G
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37127709/7976758

In `tmux`:

```
set -g set-titles on
set -g set-titles-string '#S:#I.#P #T'
setw -g automatic-rename
```

See https://superuser.com/a/430840

Comment: Thanks, that works. I ended up doing essentially this in the end, with a few hacky modifications.